# bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1

Tags: bash

I just tried to run this command:

```
/etc/ssl/acme/acme.sh --log /var/log/p3x/acme/acme.sh.log --home /etc/ssl/acme --force --issue -d patrikx3.tk -w /var/www/acme-challenge
```

I got this error:

> bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1

What is this error?

Comment: I had this occur in a `Makefile` due to how and where (inside an `ifneq` clause) I was running commands that would use `vagrant ssh -c`, I had to run it within one statement using `&&`. Maybe this will help someone.

Comment: This happened to me while developing a bash script. I accidentally pasted the command to invoke the script into the script itself. This accidentally created an infinite recursion scenario. I removed the command from my script and the the error went away. Oops!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Shell Level identify the level of sub-shell in a nested shell**

[Bash man - Shell Level SHLVL](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> SHLVL - Incremented by one each time a new instance of Bash is
>   started.

- This is intended to be a count of how deeply your Bash shells
  are nested.

As you can see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/64oq1b/til_you_can_reach_too_many_bash_levels/)

When `bash` execute itself the bash shell level is higher in 1

The following recursive call to bash:

```
$ echo "bash haha" > haha
$ bash haha
```

Got this message periodically:

> bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1

The meaning of the error above is that bash called itself 1000 times

Another example how $SHLVL variable tracks your shell nesting level:

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL
2
$ exit
$ echo $SHLVL
1
```

Comment: do you know how to get of rid this error ? i haven't changed on my server still i can see it is in CURL now: bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1

Comment: ahh i got it, i had the same curl scripts and it was recusive, that's, thanks again, ciao!