# umount bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1

Tags: bash, shell-script, unmounting

I can mount drives and images, but I can't unmount them. I get 'shell level too high'. I expect this normally happens when a script calls itself.

Is there some script that is run by umount? I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
# alias umount
-bash: alias: umount: not found
# mount -o ro sda1.img /tmp/mm
# umount /tmp/mm
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
(repeat forever)
```

Edit: Fixed incorrect copy/paste. `umount` is not aliased

Conclusion:

I needed to run `type umount` because I did not know mount was running a wrapper script instead of the actual executable

Comment: If `mount` wasn't an alias, I'd expect that first command to give you an error saying "alias: mount not found".  However, it's the `umount` command that seems to be giving you issues. What does `type -a mount umount` output?

Comment: No sorry! I copied and pasted incorrectly. Fixed it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369932/bash-warning-shell-level-1000-too-high-resetting-to-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect this normally happens when a script calls itself.

Yes, this is what's going on. A bash script keeps calling itself recursively (perhaps with other programs, i.e. it can be a loop like *script* → *other program 1* → *other program 2* → *script* …).

The `umount` program itself doesn't call a shell script. Maybe `umount` has been replaced by a buggy wrapper script? Check

```
type umount
file /path/displayed/by/the/previous/command
```

Does it happen with every filesystem type or only one? What filesystem does the image you're unmounting use? If it's a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem, all operations on it, including unmounting, involve user land code. That code can run bash scripts if it wants to. Maybe that part of the code is buggy.

Comment: @Rucent88 the answer already has `type`. If `whereis` found it, then so would `type` and of the two, `type` is the better choice when looking for executables, functions, shell keywords etc.